# Hide toolbar in android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen

Im trying to make a game for android using the canvas drawing method, but there's one problem. All my sprites were made for the specific aspect ratio of the screen, the the game doesn't take up the entire screen. Here's what it looks like.[image]

Im not sure what that area to the right with the three buttons is, but I want to hide it so I can take advantage of the entire screen. Could someone please let me know how? Thanks.

EDIT:
Here's the code for my MainActivity class.

```
package com.example.beaverduck.functionflyer.engine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your launcher screen.

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check once in AndroidManiifest.xml that the theme you are using is without action bar and then check styles.xml too.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: In both cases, im using a no action bar theme. 
AndroidManifest:android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

                                       styles:    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">